# Get the --no-index diff of files in two directories, but ignore pattern(s)

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two directories with files that are similar and I want to see the diff of any files that are different. This works:

```
git diff --no-index ./dir1 ./dir2
```

However, there are files in those directories that I want to ignore in the diff. It apparently doesn't matter whether those files are included in a `.gitignore` which I think makes sense.

Is this possible?

More context, this is for a workshop and each directory is a step in the workshop. I want to have a way to show the needed changes in each step of the workshop. The directories have some generated files and I don't want to show those generated files in the output. Additionally, I've got some `node_modules` in there which would not be desirable in the output.

Also, I like the paging functionality of `git diff`. Also, most people going through the workshop are used to `git diff`. so I do want to use this rather than some other tool.

Comment: `--no-index` turns off all the ignore features. This is internally a sensible thing to do since "ignoring" is actually a feature *of* the index, but it's kind of annoying precisely where you're wanting to use it and can't. One way to work around it is to copy the two directories (recursively) to new directories, remove the to-be-ignored files, then use `git diff` on the copies.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround idea @torek. I also like to be able to command-click in my editor on the file paths in the diff, so that workaround won't work very well for me. But it's better than nothing!

Comment: I wonder if you can do some variation of `cat $(find | grep)` to create blobs of text from each dir from the files you want, then diff those? I guess you'd lose the filenames in the diff, not sure if that matters for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to go at it. Temporarily make a commit for each directory, then diff the changesets between those two commits for those directories.

```bash
git add dir1
git commit -m "this is dir1"
git add dir2
git commit -m "this is dir2"
```

And for the final trick

```bash
git diff HEAD~1:dir1 HEAD:dir2
```

Comment: to get back to the initial commit after your actions : `git reset HEAD~2` (normal `git reset`, *not* hard reset)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation on [@Marteen Bicknese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72769520/86072), which doesn't create new commits nor modifies your index, but which still writes the content of all files to compare in your local git storage :

```
# in a script file :

export GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/my.tmp.index

git add dir1 dir2
CMP_TREE=$(git write-tree)
git diff $CMP_TREE:dir1 $CMP_TREE:dir2

rm $GIT_INDEX_FILE
```

if you're really into one liners, you can cheat and put the above
commands between parentheses :

```
(export GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/my.tmp.index; git add dir1 dir2; \
    CMP_TREE=$(git write-tree); \
    git diff $CMP_TREE:dir1 $CMP_TREE:dir2; rm $GIT_INDEX_FILE)
```

(note : parenthese start a subshell, so variables defined inside will not interfere with your current shell)

---

Turning it into a reusable script :

```
# in script file named git-dir-diff :
#!/bin/bash

path1=$1
path2=$2

export GIT_INDEX_FILE=`mktemp -u .git/my.XXXXXX.index`

git add "$path1" "$path2"
CMP_TREE=$(git write-tree)
git diff "$CMP_TREE:$path1" "$CMP_TREE:$path2"

rm $GIT_INDEX_FILE
```

if you put `git-dir-diff` in your path, you can then type :

```
git dir-diff dir1 dir2
```

additionally : if you want a more visual diff view of your directories, you can use `git difftool -d` in the script instead of `git diff`.

Comment: Rather than hardcoding `.git`, use `git rev-parse --git-dir` to locate it. There are a few remaining problems, the biggest one being that if `$path1` or `$path2` are outside the working tree, the `git add` can fail, but overall this is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to get the diff output first and then remove the diff hunks of the files you want to ignore. Here's a demo `mydiff.py` in Python(>=3.6). Disclaimer, the script is not fully tested.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import glob
import re
import sys

# the patterns of the ignored files
IGNORED_PATTERNS = [
    # regex, starting with ^
    '^.+/c\.txt$',
    # glob, starting with *. The first * is removed before being consumed.
    '***/f.txt',
    # plain, others
    'foo/a.txt',
]


def ignored(path):
    matched = False
    for pattern in IGNORED_PATTERNS:
        if pattern.startswith('^') and re.findall(pattern, path):
            matched = True
            break
        elif pattern.startswith('*'):
            globs = [
                g.replace('\\', '/')
                for g in glob.glob(pattern[1:], recursive=True)
            ]
            if path in globs:
                matched = True
                break
        elif pattern == path:
            matched = True
            break
    return matched


_local = sys.argv[1]
_remote = sys.argv[2]
cmd = 'git diff --no-index %s %s' % (_local, _remote)
o = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
lines = []
ignore = False
for line in o.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('diff --git'):
        _, _, local_path, remote_path = line.strip().split()
        local_path = '/'.join(local_path.split('/')[1:])
        remote_path = '/'.join(remote_path.split('/')[1:])
        if ignored(local_path) or ignored(remote_path):
            ignore = True
            continue
        else:
            ignore = False
            lines.append(line)
    else:
        if ignore:
            continue
        else:
            lines.append(line)
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

You could edit `IGNORED_PATTERNS` or modify the script to read the patterns from a config file.

Usage, `python mydiff.py dir1 dir2 | less`. In Git-Bash for windows, use `python.exe mydiff.py dir1 dir2 | less` to avoid the error `stdout is not a tty`, or make `mydiff.py` executable and run `./mydiff.py dir1 dir2 | less`.